# Dynamically build record type to fetch into

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'd like to collect rows from a dynamic sql query into a pl/sql row. The problem is the query is built dynamically and I'm not sure what all columns will be there. The result set is based on a table in my DB (t1 in the example) + one additional column (sid in the example). It seems impossible to create this record type dynamically and fetch the records from the dynamic sql into it.

PLS-00597: expression 't_row' in the INTO list is of wrong type

Is it possible to do this in any other way?

Please note the code has been simplified for convenient reading:

```
DECLARE
  v_query_string VARCHAR2(32767 BYTE);

  TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
  cur ref_cursor; 

  TYPE rec_type IS RECORD (
    sid number,  
    struct t1%ROWTYPE);

  t_row rec_type;

BEGIN

  --build v_query_string -> select sid,t1.a,t1.b,t1.c,t1.some_column_from_t1 from t1

  OPEN cur FOR v_query_string;
  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO t_row;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(t_row.some_column_from_t1);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur;

END;
```

Comment: Can you show your DDL table ? Anyway you you should use **t_row.sid** which is in **rec_type**

Comment: @Frank I updated the DBMS_OUTPUT line to make more clear that I want to access any column from the t1 table (hence t1%ROWTYPE in rec_type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a dynamic cursor, which is very easy to read and doesn't require extra data types or variables declared. In your sample SQL, you could do this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR cv IN (select sid, t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.some_column_from_t1 from t1)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cv.some_column_from_t1);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Note that this does not work with SQL built on the fly and stored in a variable, but you would be able to access any column in the table with a simple `SELECT * FROM t1;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DMBS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS` function.

Example

```
   DECLARE
       cur PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
       cols DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
       col_num PLS_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
       DBMS_SQL.PARSE
          (cur, 'SELECT * FROM table', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
       // Retrieving column information
       DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS (cur, col_num, cols);
      ...
    END;
```

You can get more infor from this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055145.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 TYPE rec_type IS RECORD (
    sid number,  
    somefield t1.somefield%TYPE
    ...);

  t_row rec_type;
```

and you can access to data in this way :

```
t_row.sid etc...
```

Comment: the sid column is not part of the t1 table structure, it's a derived value

Comment: Maybe you cannot do in that way , but you can transform **struct** in N variables from t1 table , i will edit the answer